# Get Process Total Page Faults

Tags: windows, winapi, page-fault

Both Task Manager and SysInternals Process Explorer show the total amount of a process's page-fault, but all Performance Counters and WMI objects I found show only Page-Faults per second,

Is there a different API or some obscure performance counter that does show the total amount of Page-Faults for a certain process? (on Windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GetProcessMemoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'s `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS` has a count in `PageFaultCount`.